# await user pins in discord.py?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

When awaiting a pin with `on_guild_channel_pins_update`, both pin and unpin actions are detected. I am looking to get the message ID of a message the second it is pinned. However, this method's only parameters are `channel`, returning the channel where the pin action was detected, and `last_pin`, which returns only a UTC timestamp of the most recently pinned message in `channel`, regardless of the message that triggered the function in the first place. If this function did not include unpin actions, I could simply use `await channel.pins()` to get a list of all the pins in the channel and use the message ID of whatever is at index 0, but because this function triggers even when a pin is removed, this creates several cases where the bot would return something that has been pinned for months.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using [`on_message_edit()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_message_edit#discord.on_message_edit), which triggers whenever something happens to a message, which includes being pinned.

```py
@client.event
async def on_message_edit(before, after):
    if not before.pinned and after.pinned:  # check if the action was a message being pinned
        print(after.id)                     # do whatever you want with the ID
```